# Erratic values when I use fstream with for, C++

Tags: c++

I need to write the output of a loop in an external file but I receive erratic values, my program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("afile.dat");

    float a[6];

    for (int i=0;i<6; i++){
        outfile <<a[i]<<endl;
    }

    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The output file:

```
2.8026e-45
0
8.40779e-45
-0
0
0
```

Instead of:

```
0 
1
2
3
4
5
```

I don't know what's wrong, could anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Try initializing the array `a[6]` with meaninful values, or, in your for loop, try this: `outfile << i <<endl;`

Comment: Amadeus, this little code is a small example to explain the doubt, the real code has more than 1000 array elements.

Comment: I can not talk about your real array, but this snippet shows that you haven't initialized it. I

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invoking undefined behavior.
`float a[6]` is not initialized.
The C++ standard makes no guarantees about what data will be found in an uninitialized array.

Initialize your array like so `float a[6]{};` before trying to read from it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are outputting the uninitialized contents of `a`.  This is undefined behavior.

If you want to output the value of `i`, replace

```
outfile << a[i] << endl;
```

with

```
outfile << i << endl;
```